# How is the Correct use of ui:repeat tag to build a selctOneMenu in XHTML using JBoss Seam Framework?

Tags: xhtml, jboss, for-loop, seam

This is suppose to be quite simple but I have already spent couple of hours on this without solution. My fragment of code follows:

```
<h:selectOneMenu id="carro" value="#{abastecimentoAction.idCarroPesquisa}" required="true">
     <ui:repeat value="#{carroList.resultList}" var="_meuCarro">
        <f:selectItem itemValue="#{_meuCarro.id}" itemLabel="#{_meuCarro.nome}"/>         
        <h:outputText value="Testes"/>
     </ui:repeat>
 </h:selectOneMenu>
```

The point is the "Testes" string is correctly printed as many times as the size of carroList.resultList but no options is printed. I get a blank combo.

tx in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just managed to fix this using:

```
<h:selectOneMenu id="carro" value="#{abastecimentoAction.idCarroPesquisa}" required="false">
     <s:selectItems var="carro" value="#{carroList.resultList}" label="#{carro.nome}" itemValue="#{carro.id}" />
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

Comment: Easy right? :-) You gotta love Seam when using JSF. If you get time read this http://shervinasgari.blogspot.com/2010/10/why-you-should-not-use-seam-application.html It will show you why you should be careful about the Seam Application Framework (not Seam it self)

Comment: Thank you I will read it. And yes I do use JSF with Facelets and I am very impressed about seam. Did you mentioned the link because of my use of #{carroList.resultList}? Anyway, I will read your post. regards.

Comment: Yes, thats why I mentioned it